# Count a specific character in a column

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any way I can count the number of times a character is found in a string of text in an entire column in Excel?

```
  F
  **Static**
1 {@DWXBZ}
2 {MTZXBWDGSI!P}
3 {GWDPZ}
4 {EDG@ZW}
5 {DWZVMTPE@GBXSKIJ%ONA!IJ}
```

So for example, I want to count the number of times the letter D appears in the entire column of F. I would like to display this value in a specific cell for a report.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/213889

Answer (score 2):

You could use this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LEN($F$1:$F$5)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($F$1:$F$5,"D","")))
```

Replaces all the "D"s with nothing and subtracts the length from the full length.  The Sumproduct keeps count.

[image]

Comment: And OP wants entire column, so use `=SUMPRODUCT(LEN($F:$F)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($F:$F,"D","")))`